# How to redirect from external URL to a chrome extension URL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm working on a google extension that creates a window using:

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: '/panel.html',
  focused: false,
  incognito: true,
});
```

This window then redirects to an external URL in Amazon Cognito for login, after successfully login in Cognito automatically redirects back to any url, in this case I have it configured to go back to the initial extension url with some tokens that Cognito adds:

```
chrome-extension://cldaoofoaaihnfldlpmcfhdmfjjgfmje/panel.html#id_token=[tokens-added-by-cognito]
```

But instead of loading the initial page chrome is blocking the extension from being loaded with the message `my-extension-id` is blocked.

[image: The error after redirecting back to the extension]

Copying the url into a new tab loads the extension properly, why is it getting blocked in the first place and how do I properly configure it so it loads after redirecting from an external URL?

This is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScripts.js"]
    }
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    { "resources": ["src/img/*.svg"], "matches": ["<all_urls>"] }
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"],
  "incognito": "split"
}
```

Comment: Either add panel.html to web_accessible_resources or use webRequest API to detect the redirected URL and open it explicitly via chrome.tabs.update.

Comment: @wOxxOm Adding "panel.html" to web_accessible_resources was the solution, thank you!